# Could anyone simplify this JS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simplify it to an ELSE IF or Case Statement or anything that could make it more simple. Thanks!

```
   $(function() {
    $('#Class').change(function() { 
     $('#YearLevel,#Dept,#Course,#SY,#Section,#Subject,#appointment').val('');
      this.form.submit();
    });
});

   $(function() {
    $('#YearLevel').change(function() { 
     $('#Dept,#Course,#SY,#Section,#Subject,#appointment').val('');
      this.form.submit();
    });
});

   $(function() {
    $('#Dept').change(function() {  
     $('#Course,#SY,#Section,#Subject,#appointment').val('');
      this.form.submit();
    });
});

 etc...
```

Comment: This is not a "do it for me" platform. You have to show where you have made an attempt, not just ask for someone else to do it. Consider looking at the jquery site on the use of multiple selectors.

Comment: This code already looks pretty simple.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Not a lot you can do to simplify that other than wrap all the event handler assignment in a single `$(function() {` ... `});`

Comment: Since each list of IDs having its value set to `""` is reduced by one item, does that imply an order in the document? If so, that would be useful in simplifying.

Comment: i want something like var some = ('a,b,c,d'); $(function(){ IF... ELSE IF...}

Comment: So yes? No? Does your list of IDs correspond to an order in which they appear in the document?

Comment: I tried but I can't get work. Thank you anyway, just asking if someone could :) @Kramb

Comment: yes it does sir  @llama

Comment: Awesome. Do they all share a common parent?

Comment: Actually the common parent doesn't matter. I thought jQuery had some facility to select elements after another at otherwise arbitrary positions in the DOM. (I quit using jQuery *years* ago.) So my solution below will be about as short, fast and simple as you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should do what you want.

```
var t = '#Class,#YearLevel,#Dept,#Course,#SY,#Section,#Subject,#appointment'

$(function() {
  $(t).change(function() {
    var id = "#" + this.id;
    var s = t.split(id);
    s = s[1].match("^,") == null ? s[1] : s[1].substring(1, s[1].length)
    $(s).val('');
    //this.form.submit();
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var t = '#Class,#YearLevel,#Dept,#Course,#SY,#Section,#Subject,#appointment'

$(function() {
  $(t).change(function() {
    var id = "#" + this.id;
    var s = t.split(id);
    s = s[1].match("^,") == null ? s[1] : s[1].substring(1, s[1].length)
    $(s).val('');
    //this.form.submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Class" />
<input id="YearLevel" />
<input id="Dept" />
<input id="Course" />
<input id="SY" />
<input id="Section" />
<input id="Subject" />
<input id="appointment" />
```

Comment: Oh that's brilliant!

Comment: @JaromandaX Cheers for the kind words

Comment: probably breaks if you fire change handler on #appointment

Comment: though, `var id = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + ",";` is `var id = this.id` :p - you could even `$(t.split('#' + this.id + ',')[1]).val('');` just to make Brendan Eich weep :p

Comment: @James, jQuery is very very forgiving, so it probably wouldn't :p

Comment: I've changed it a bit.

Comment: couldn't you just `var s = (t + ',').split(id);` - though, your original code did not break at all as far as I could tell ... `$(undefined)` doesn't break jQuery

Comment: the handler for #appointment now sets `$(“”).val(“”);`  I guess that’s ok, kind of useless though.  Might want to check `if (s)` first, or not assign a handler to #appointment at all, but now it’s getting complex.

Comment: thank you @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 1):

Since according to your comments there's an implied order in the document, you can simply give each element a common class, and then select those elements to bind the same handler.

In the handler, you take a subslice of the elements starting at the one after the one that received the event, and use that to set the value.

```js
$(function() {
  var elems = $(".myClass").change(function() {
    elems.slice($.inArray(this, elems)+1).val("");
    // this.form.submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input class="myClass" id="Class" />
    <input class="myClass" id="YearLevel" />
    <input class="myClass" id="Dept" />
    <input class="myClass" id="Course" />
    <input class="myClass" id="SY" />
    <input class="myClass" id="Section" />
    <input class="myClass" id="Subject" />
    <input class="myClass" id="appointment" />
</form>
```

If you can't modify the HTML to give a common class, you can simply put the list of IDs back in where the `.myClass` currently goes, and it'll work just the same.